# $E(x) \equiv 17x + 4 \pmod{26}$

Tags: number-theory

$E(x) \equiv 17x + 4 \pmod{26}$

the numbers 4,7 and 15 need deciphered

My answer spells ART correct me if wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right.
We may verify that $E^{-1}(x)=23x+12$:
$$23(17x+4)+12=(15\cdot 26+1)x+4\cdot 26\equiv x \pmod{26}.$$
Hence, by using $E^{-1}$, $(4,7,15)$ becomes $(0,17,19)$, that is "ART" (according to the english alphabet).

Answer (score 0):

Correct, $\,17x\!+\!4\,$ has inverse $\,17^{-1}(x\!-\!4)\equiv 12\!-\!3x\ $ by $\ \dfrac{1}{17}\equiv \dfrac{1}{-9}\equiv\dfrac{3}{-27}\equiv \dfrac{3}{-1}$

Therefore $\ 12\!-\!3x\ $ decodes $\, 4,7,15\, \mapsto\, 0,17,19\,\mapsto\, $ A,R,T in English